# Does Windows 10 support Visual C++ 6?

Tags: visual-c++, windows-10

I am using Visual C++ 6 SP6, It works fine on Windows 8.1. Just wondering if MS is continuing the support in Windows 10.

Comment: Microsoft hasn't been supporting VC++6 for a long time. But MS is continuing to support running old software on Windows 10, no matter where it comes from, so you probably can still run VC++6 on Windows 10.

Comment: If you have a spare computer (or can setup a VM) then try [installing the preview](http://insider.windows.com) and check if your app runs. If not, use the Feedback tool to send a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my PC, yes, but it was tough to install - if you already have it installed and upgrade to Windows 10, this may not be an issue.

SETUP.EXE froze after copying files. I attached Visual Studio 2015's debugger to the process, kept stepping through and found an infinite loop, which I skipped using the "Set Next Statement" command. I got a message box asking if I wished to update the JIT settings (I chose No) and Setup ended. I then installed SP6 over the top, choosing not to replace files when prompted.